# d3.js v4 scaleOrdinal not all items are displayed?

Tags: d3.js, char

I have a problem with scaleOrdinal. Not all items of dataset are displayed. The code is:

```
   const displayValues = ["10:06", "10:36", "11:06", "11:36", "12:06", "12:36", "13:06", "13:36", "14:06", "14:36", "15:06", "15:36", "10:06", "10:36", "11:06", "11:36", "12:06", "12:36", "13:06", "13:36", "14:06", "14:36", "15:06", "15:36"];
   const positions = [0, 75, 150, 225, 300, 375, 450, 525, 600, 675, 750, 825, 900, 975, 1050, 1125, 1200, 1275, 1350, 1425, 1500, 1575, 1650, 1725];
   const xOrdinalRange = scaleOrdinal()
                            .domain(displayValues)
                            .range(positions);
   const xOrdinalAxis = axisBottom(xOrdinalRange);
   
   this.svgChart.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${this.height - 50})`)
        .call(xOrdinalAxis);
```

What I get is:

[image]

The problem is in axis?

Comment: The axis is displayed correctly. `displayValues` has values repeated after the 12th element. Please review it.

Comment: And btw: If `const xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["a","b","c","a"])`, then `xScale.domain() => ["a","b","c"]` and NOT `["a", "b", "c", "a"]`. I hope I clarify the point here.